# TCP handshake: at which point exactly the connection is considered established and data can be sent?

Tags: tcp

TCP 3-way handshake consists of SYN, SYN-ACK and ACK packets.

My question is: can a server (i.e. the one that accepts the connection) send the data right after sending the SYN-ACK, or nothing can be sent prior to receiving the first ACK?

In other words, if the server sends data on the socket right after accepting the connection, how many round-trips would it take for the client to start receiving it. Would it be just 1 round trip (i.e. SYN from client, and SYN-ACK + data packets from server)? Or at least 2 round trips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't entirely correct.  There are two cases that it fails to address.

The first is TCP Fast Open.  This is defined in RFC 7413.  It is specifically designed to allow a server to begin processing data sent on the SYN, even sending responsive data in the SYN ACK, not needing the final ACK of the three way handshake.

The second is that RFC 793 for TCP actually does permit data on the SYN; however, this data is not *processed* (excepting fast open) until the connection completes.  If the connection never completes, the data is obviously dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. My goal is to design a protocol over TCP with minimum latency. I guess T/TCP isn't applicable to my case, since data isn't actually delivered to the server. Do you know what's availability of TFO? Is it supported by current ios/android platforms?

Answer (score 1):

The server can't send anything until the final ACK, because it doesn't have an accepted socket until then. `accept()` doesn't return until the handshake is complete.

Comment: Thanks, that's what seems to me as well, but I'm not sure. Are you sure about that?

Comment: If I wasn't sure I wouldn't have posted it. One thing that really ticks me off is being asked to confirm or restate things I have already stated.

Comment: Then may you point-out what makes you confident about this? I know that theoretically after sending the SYN+ACK the TCP state machine goes to SYN_RECEIVED state. However it *seems* that practically there's no problem to report connection accepted to the application and send the data right away. And this makes actually sense, in order to minimize latency.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete.  Data on the SYN is permitted by RFC.  Read my additional answer.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Certainly, but the application can't send that data, because it doesn't have a socket yet.

Comment: @valdo I've given my reason. It is a logical inference from the timing of the socket creation.

Comment: You are incorrect.  The entire *purpose* of fast open is for the receiving application to be able to begin processing the data before the connection is completed.  Under the original RFC, data on the SYN is held until the connection is completed.  There would be no point to fast open if the data behavior did not change.  Data on the syn was always possible (and legal).

Answer (score 1):

When client sends the first syn packet , client will be in SYN_SENT state , and waits for SYN/ACK from server .
Server will keep listening on the socket . When it receives the SYN , server goes to SYN_REVD state.  Now it sends SYN/ACK to client and it allocates buffers and sets variables like congwin , threshold etc...When client receives SYN/ACk it goes to ESTABLISHED STATE and acknowledges the server with ACK . Now the client can send data in ack segment or not . After server receives ack it goes into established state .
Now both client and server are in established state and can exchange  data.

When client receives SYN/ACk it will allocate the buffers and variables at its side and then sends ACK to server.

To understand these states, try using netstat command in linux and you can see the states of the socket